# Accessing Encrypted Home Folder / Return to Login Screen

Tags: 11.10, login, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I been having problems with ubuntu, in that I can reach the login screen, but when I enter my password it comes up with a black screen with some text and takes me back to the login screen - I can login in terminal mode. After trying several fixes posted on the Internet I decided to just reinstall Ubuntu, since I don't have anything important on. However I did want to backup my Home folder. This folder was encrypted on installation. When I try to access it from the LiveCD version of Ubuntu, it displays a readme.txt file that tells me to run
`ecryptfs-mount-private`. I run this and it displays the error 'Encrypted private directory is not setup properly'. Any solutions to both of these problems would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the methods listed in those posts, and I still can't access my files. I don't have my mount passphrase, and when I try to get it using `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/daniel/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` but it comes up with the error:

```
Error: Unwrapping passphrase failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

However, `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private` worked.

Comment: I was just about to chime in and recommend ecryptfs-recover-private.  That's definitely the right way to go!

Comment: What did the system log have to say with regard to `libecryptfs`?